# Unable To Set Value For Part Of An Array

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application, on one screen, it has a series of text boxes as shown bellow:

[image]

The content of this window is generated from control templates and when a button is pressed it runs this method to update the values to a public object within the class(thisPMX as shown in the code bellow):

```
private void UpdatePMX()
    {
        thisPMX.Name = tbName.Text;
        thisPMX.Month = tbMonth.Text;
        thisPMX.Day = tbDay.Text;
        thisPMX.Year = tbYear.Text;

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            string thisBehavior = "Behavior0" + (i + 1).ToString();

            ControlTemplate temp = ((Label)this.FindName(thisBehavior)).Template;

            if(((TextBox)temp.FindName("BName", behaviors[i])).Text.Length > 0)
            {
                thisPMX.Behaviors[i].Name = ((TextBox)temp.FindName("BName", behaviors[i])).Text;
            }

            if (((TextBox)temp.FindName("BehaviorWeight", behaviors[i])).Text.Length > 0)
            {
                thisPMX.Behaviors[i].Weight = ((TextBox)temp.FindName("BehaviorWeight", behaviors[i])).Text;
            }

            for(int e = 0; e < 10; e++)
            {
                if (((TextBox)temp.FindName(("S" + ((e + 1).ToString())), behaviors[i])).Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    string scoreInst = ((TextBox)temp.FindName("S" + (e + 1).ToString(), behaviors[i])).Text;
                    thisPMX.Behaviors[i].SAll[e] = (scoreInst.ToString().Trim());
                    string Inst = thisPMX.Behaviors[i].SAll[e]; // Break Here For Testing Value
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This method works as expected up until the last for statement where is't updating the values from the possible scores boxes. At this point I added the strings around it for debugging as you can see above. When I place a breakpoint at the point noted by the comment, the value for scoreInst is "1" i is 0 and e is 0 but when I assign scoreInst to `thisPMX.Behaviors[i].SAll[e]` it doesn't seem to accept the value and Inst comes out to be null.

Here is the class for Behavior which houses the SAll string[]:

```
public class Behavior
{
    public Behavior()
    {

    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string BehaviorMeasure { get; set; }

    public string Weight { get; set; }

    public string S1 { get; set; }

    public string S2 { get; set; }

    public string S3 { get; set; }

    public string S4 { get; set; }

    public string S5 { get; set; }

    public string S6 { get; set; }

    public string S7 { get; set; }

    public string S8 { get; set; }

    public string S9 { get; set; }

    public string S10 { get; set; }

    public bool ValuesSatisfied
    {
        get
        {
            if ((ActiveScores < 3) || !(BehaviorMeasure.Length == 0) || !(Weight.Length == 0) || !(Name.Length == 0))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool HasActiveValues
    {
        get
        {
            if (Name != null && Weight != null)
            {
                if ((ActiveScores > 0) || (Name.Length > 0) || (Weight.Length > 0))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public string[] SAll 
    { 
        get
        {
            string[] Scores = { S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10 };
            return Scores;
        }      
    }

    public int ActiveScores
    {
        get
        {
            int count = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < SAll.Length; i++)
            {
                if (SAll[i] != null && SAll[i].Length > 0)
                {
                    ++count;
                }
            }

            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get any exceptions or errors but the values from the Possible Scores TextBoxes aren't being set the the SAll Array values when the UpdatePMX() Method is called.

The desired outcome would be for this method to be able to successfully carry the values from the various textboxes in the xaml to the various Behavior values in the "thisPMX" class instance.

**Notes:**

thisPMX is a public class instance in which it has 8 instances of the Behaviors class shown above.

If any more information is need please let me know otherwise thank you for the help.

Comment: are you just `Coding and Going` meaning are you not debugging ..? what do you see when you use the `Debugger`

Comment: Where do you initialize `Behavior`? I don't see any call for the default constructor. Are you using it as a `static` class?

Comment: it's not a static class I think when using objects in a for loop or foreach loop it's customary depending on it's usage to `new the Object` as well but I don't have time to personally read line by line his code.. debugging may have saved him a lot of headache as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you the values you are setting in `SAll` are always being lost because `SAll` is always returning a new Array. So, when you try to get the data from the array you just inserted into, you are really just getting a new array.

Problem code:

```
public string[] SAll 
{ 
    get
    {
        string[] Scores = { S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10 };
        return Scores;
    }      
}
```

should be something more like :

```
private string[] _sAll;
public string[] SAll 
{ 
    get
    {
        if(_sAll == null)
          _sAll = { S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10 };
        return _sAll;
    }      
}
```

However, any changes in the array would NOT be reflected back into `S1`, `S2`, etc. So, it might be better to change those to be something more like:

```
public String S1 
{
  get{ return SAll[0];}
  set{ SAll[0] = value;}
}
```